# Two-way Communication with Delphi Client and ASP.Net Server

Tags: asp.net, delphi

I need to develop an application which would run in a corporate network. The client should both receive commands (shutdown, restart, ...) and send info (something happened, ...) from/to the server. So, using a web interface, the network administrator would be able to see what clients are connected, send commands to them, and see real-time info coming from them. The client should be written in Delphi (normal VCL forms with Edits, etc.) and the server "preferably" in ASP.Net.

I researched a bit and I think WebSockets might be good to achieve this. I plan to use some WebSocket libraries for Delphi like [this](https://github.com/andremussche/DelphiWebsockets). I'm not sure what technology I should use for the server.

Please tell me if WebSockets is good for my requirements. Other solutions are welcome (maybe writing the server in Delphi?).

Comment: What will the client side user "see" in the user interface - a web page or a normal Delphi GUI window with Edit fields, Buttons etc.?

Comment: From the signalr docs I can see it designed to work with web browsers and (Chrome, Firefox, ...) and requires JavaScript client-side. You can not use Delphi WebSocket libraries with it, because these communicate with the WebSocket server directly, not via the web browser.

Comment: @mjn, a normal Delphi GUI (VCL). Thanks for your comment about SignalR. I should be thinking of something else for the server!

Comment: Please update your question to clarify the question, why is SignalR no longer suiting your needs and how your client should look like: a VCL app with buttons, edit fields etc., or a VCL app with embedded webbrowser ... ... ..., or do require support for both normal web browsers and VCL app based clients at the same time.

Comment: @mjn, I updated the question and removed SignalR tag. Maybe I'm not being understood correctly here. The client is a normal VCL with edits, etc. The server is another beast with a web interface, so that the network admin can monitor and manage it. These two, should communicate in some way to cover my needs. I'm looking for the best option available. Thanks.

Comment: @mjn, Wait a minute! I just remembered that SignalR has Winforms clients too. So it is not limited to browser clients.

Answer (score 2):

Web interfaces typically are HTML based views, and require a web HTTP server and a web browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.). Delphi Web Socket client libraries however can only be used to talk with a Web Socket server from within a native Delphi application, for example a VCL GUI.

If you plan to write a VCL application (not web browser based), you have other transport protocol options besides Web Sockets, which are widely used in small and large systems:

- [MQTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) (formerly Message Queue Telemetry Transport)
- [STOMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_Text_Oriented_Messaging_Protocol) (Streaming Text Oriented Messaging Protocol)
- [AMQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) (Advanced Message Queuing Protocol)
- [MSMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) (Microsoft Message Queuing)

As with WebSockets, these protocols offer asynchronous / bi-directional messaging. On the server side you can choose from many production quality implementations of these protocols (known as 'message brokers'), mostly free / open source. Similar to HTTP, message payload can be anything - text or binary data - and messages can use headers to provide application-defined metadata.

Your server-side application code can be written in Delphi, and is only another client of the message broker, communicating with the client applications over the message broker protocol. As soon as client and server are connected to the message broker, messages can flow in both directions.

Many advanced features are included in message brokers: if a client disconnects while the server is still sending messages, the message broker can store these messages and deliver them as soon as the client reconnects.

For most of these protocols I have seen client libraries or wrappers for Delphi / Object Pascal, free and open source or commercial.

Comment: I need the client to be VCL, but the server be web-based. What is the best combination I can use?

Comment: @Delphi.Boy please clarify what "web-based" means, a HTTP server, serving HTML to web clients (Chrome, Firefox, etc.)?

Comment: I mean like a normal ASP.Net project. Being hosted in IIS, a user can type the address in a web browser and work with it.